# Trying to find the ARN pattern for AWS WAF regional

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-application-firewall

I'm playing around with writing IAM policies for an AWS WAF regional resource. I've created a rule for which I'm trying to see if I can write an IAM policy. That's where I realized that IAM policies require ARNs and not just resource Ids.

I used the GetRule API to see if that returns the ARN of the rule and it doesn't. It only returns the ID. I checked the AWS docs now:

```
1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-api-permissions-ref.html
```

The ARN pattern is a little confusing, the first document points out the pattern to be `arn:aws:waf-regional::account-id:resource-type/resource-id`, but the example below has a specific region in there.

Same happens with the second document for writing IAM policies, WAF regional does seem to have a region in the ARN. Now where can I get the ARN for this resource? And which document should I be referring as the source of truth?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this frustrating as well.  awscli get-rule does not return the ARN.  get-web-acl does however so I used the pattern from that and it worked when passing it to the ResourceARN field for the other rule endpoints.  I can't say whether it will work for use in IAM policies but this is the format that worked for me:

```
arn:aws:waf-regional:<your-region>:<your-account-id>:rule/<rule-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for the ARN for the the rule, but the format for the regional WAF ARN may help to determine the rule ARN format as well.

```
arn:aws:wafv2:<aws-region>:<Account ID>:regional/webacl/<web-acl-name>/<web-acl-id>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).